# Waiting for Delegate Callback in SwiftUI ViewModel then execute code further

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

`I'm working on a Swift/SwiftUI project where I'm using a UIViewControllerRepresentable to present a STPPaymentHandler for  3D authentication. The 3D authentication process involves interaction with a delegate that resides in the UIViewControllerRepresentable. After toggling the presentation of the web view, I need to wait for the delegate callback before proceeding with other actions in my SwiftUI ViewModel.

My code in ViewModel:

```
 {
            self.loadingState = .loading // start loading
    do {
        /**
         - If user is going to pay from card screen it is going to use selectPaymentCar else card will be used
         */
        if  let paymentCard = selectPaymentCard{
            
            let request = try await walletServices.createSubscription(priceId: self.selectedSubscription!.id, paymentMethod: paymentCard.type, paymentDetails: ["name": name], paymentMethodId: paymentCard.id)
            
            if request.next_action != nil {
                /// the card requires three d authentication
                self.clientSecret = request.client_secret
                if self.clientSecret != nil { // if client secret is not nil then show the webview
                    self.present3dView.toggle()
                  
                    
                    if is3dSuccess == "success"{
                        /// if 3d auth is completed then confirm the subscription
                   
                        let stripeID = retrieveIntent(self.clientSecret!) // get the payment intent id i.e stripe id
                        let isSuccessSubscription = try await self.confirmSubscription(stripeId: stripeID, card: paymentCard)
                        
                        if isSuccessSubscription {
                            self.subscriptionState = .success
                            self.successMessage = "Subscription Successful"
                            
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5){
                                self.loadingState = .loaded
                                self.subscriptionState = .idle
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.subscriptionState = .failed // show Error
                            self.errorMessage = "Payment Failed"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return  await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
                print(request)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if request.status == "incomplete"{
                        self.loadingState = .failed // show Error
                        self.errorMessage = "Payment Failed"
                    }else{
                        self.loadingState = .loaded// End loading                            
                        self.subscriptionState = .success
                    }
                }
                
                continuation.resume(returning: request.status ?? "")
                
            }
        }else{
            guard let card = card else {
                return ""
                self.loadingState = .failed
            }
            let request = try await walletServices.createSubscription(priceId: self.selectedSubscription!.id, paymentMethod: card.paymentMethodType, paymentDetails: ["name": name], paymentMethodId: card.paymentId)
            return  await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
                Task{
                    if savingNewCard {
                        //Call confirm Payment
                        /**
                         - API Response changed so commenting out below code
                         */
                        //try await confirmPayment(request.clientSecret, paymentMethodId: card.paymentId)
                    }
                }
               
                continuation.resume(returning: request.status ?? "")
                
            }
        }

   
        
    }catch let error {
        
        print("ERROR PROCESSING SUBSCRIPTION \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    self.loadingState = .failed
    return ""
}`
```

after this  self.present3dView.toggle() I need wait for call back of the delegate and then execute rest of the code

My UIViewRepresentable code:

```
 `class Coordinator: NSObject,STPAuthenticationContext,     PaymentHandlerDelegate {
    
    
   
    
    var parent: PaymentHandlerView
   
    
    init(_ parent: PaymentHandlerView) {
           self.parent = parent
           super.init()
           parent.VC.delegate = self  // Set the delegate
       }
    
    func didFinishPaymentAuthentication(_ success: Bool, value: String) {
        parent.isSuccess.wrappedValue = success
        parent.successMessage.wrappedValue = value
    }
   
    
    func authenticationPresentingViewController() ->     UIViewController {
        return parent.VC
    }        

}`
```

My View controller code for STPHandler:

`

```
#if !EXTENSION

   func handleAuthenticationStatus(_ clientSecret: String) async  throws {

       let response =  try await STPPaymentHandler.sharedHandler.confirmSetupIntent(STPSetupIntentConfirmParams(clientSecret: clientSecret), with: self) {[weak self] nextAction, _, error in
            switch nextAction {
            case .succeeded:
                ///Dismiss the View
                print("Succeeded")
                self?.delegate?.didFinishPaymentAuthentication(true,value: "success")
            case .canceled:
                print("canceld")
                self?.delegate?.didFinishPaymentAuthentication(false, value: "cancelled")
            case .failed:
                print("failed")
                self?.delegate?.didFinishPaymentAuthentication(false, value: "failed")
            }
        }
    }
    #endif`
```

and I am using a swiftUI View as bridge between UIViewRepresentable and ViewModel:

`

```
  struct PaymentWebView: View {


 @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: PaymentViewModel
 // let url: URL
let clientSecret: String
@State var isSuccess: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    PaymentHandlerView(clientSecret: clientSecret, isSuccess: $isSuccess, successMessage: $viewModel.is3dSuccess)
        .onChange(of: isSuccess) { newValue in
            if newValue {
                //Dismiss the view
                viewModel.present3dView = false
            }
        }
}
}
 `
```

After toggle I want to wait for the delegate call back and then execute rest of my code for that function I am not sure how to achieve this. This line if is3dSuccess == "success" should only be executed after my delegate call back.

I tried using a while loop until success message is change but that block the UI and won't let my ViewController load fully.

Comment: You don't "wait" as such. You have a state in your view model that triggers a refresh of your view

Comment: @Paulw11 I update the state based on success or failure but the issue here is after self.present3dView.toggle() is called I need to wait for the call back of STPPAyment handler and then execute rest of the function because it will update is3dSuccess and based on that I will execute further code

Comment: You could use async/await with a checked continuation. You can store a continuation in a property and then resume it in your delegate method.

Comment: How about passing closure?

Comment: @HemantStha thank you for you reply but I used continuation